# Вернуть объект на основании пересечения строк из двух массивов

Tags: javascript

Есть проверочный массив:

```
const someStrings = ['google', 'facebook', 'instagram'];
```

Есть массив строк, который я получаю с бэка, там может быть любое количество строк.
Например с бэка я получил такой массив:

```
const linksFromBack = ['www.google.com', '' , 'stackoverflow.com', 'instagram.com'];
```

Нужно вернуть объект в котором ключ будет назван по элементу из массива someStrings, а его значение  будет элементом из второго массива, который содержит подстроку из первого.
Вид возвращаемого объекта:

```
  const linksObject = {
      google: 'www.google.com',
      facebook: '',
      instagram: 'instagram.com',
    };
```

Comment: Как пробовали решить эту задачу вы?

Comment: и если во втором массиве будет несколько соответствий, то что? собственно, что вам мешает тут циклом пройтись под ключам, и внутри поискать что надо, запихивая результат в объект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали такое решение

```
Object.fromEntries(someStrings.map(item=>{
    return [item, linksFromBack.find(link=>link.includes(item)) || '']
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что такое решение подойдет.

```
const someStrings = ['google', 'facebook', 'instagram'];
const linksFromBack = ['www.google.com', '', 'stackoverflow.com', 'instagram.com'];

const getLinkObj = (keys, values) => {
  const linkObj = {};
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    const value = values.find((value) => value.match(key));
    linkObj[key] = value ?? '';
  });
  return linkObj;
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, подходит.

Comment: @МаксимБондаренко, ну так если подходит - отметьте ответ "верным"